# Getting the available view for the sharepoint list and populating into the dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010

```
             1. Here the sample code i tried for getting the available views for the
                sharepoint list and populating into the dropdownlist

          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url);
                    foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
                    {
                        SPListCollection spListCollection = web.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.GenericList);

                        foreach (SPList splist in spListCollection)
                        {
                            ListNameList.Items.Add(splist.Title.ToString());                        
                        }
                        ListNameList.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");

                    }
                }
}

                       protected void ListNameList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
                           {
                            SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url);
                            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
                            SPList selectedlist = web.Lists[ListNameList.SelectedValue];
                            foreach (SPView views in selectedlist.Views)
                            {
                                ViewNameList.Items.Add(views.Views.ToString());
                            }
                          }
```

1. I created the views in the sharepoint list,but in the above code
   while looping i got the viewnames properly but when populating into
   the dropdown list the output i am getting like Microsoft.Sharepoint
   instaed of viewnames.

   ```
       Can you help me out of this?
   ```

Comment: Shouldn't the line "ViewNameList.Items.Add(views.Views.ToString());" be "views.Title"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to edit the line where you add in the new Item to the ViewNameList to use view.Title

```
protected void ListNameList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url);
    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
    SPList selectedlist = web.Lists[ListNameList.SelectedValue];
    foreach (SPView views in selectedlist.Views)
    {
        ViewNameList.Items.Add(views.Title);
    }
}
```

You also may want to order the views if the collection is not returning them in the order that you want.